# Is DB2 instance the same as a database instance?

Tags: database, db2, instance

I am pretty confused trying to figure out the difference between a DB2 instance and a database instance. I did quite a bit of search online, but almost all comes up with 'database instances'.

From what I have gathered, a database instance consists of the RDBMS software along with tables and other structures.

My doubt is whether there is such a thing as a 'DB2 instance' or is it the same as a database instance?

Comment: DB2 is vendor specific and provided by IBM; such as SQL Server from Microsoft, Postgres, MySQL, etc... While all could provide database instances, a DB2 instance will only come from a DB2 server.

Comment: So basically a 'DB2 instance' is what a database instance would be called in the DB2 realm?

Thanks

Comment: For DB2 on Linux, UNIX, and Windows platforms, there is really only one type of instance, so documentation that refers to both a "DB2 instance" and a "database instance" is misleading and unfortunate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Information Center article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0004900.html) on instances.

Basically, you can have multiple instances of DB2 running on the same physical machine, and each of those instances can have their own separate databases, administration groups, tunings, etc.

This applies to DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows.  I believe the rough equivalent would be "[subsystem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_dbzinzosenvironment.dita?lang=en)" in z/OS-land.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 is a Database from IBM. http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/

So "an instance of DB2" is a database instance, but a database instance is not always "an instance of DB2".

Comment: My first notion was that a DB2 instance refers to a server space (sort of a logical grouping) created to hold multiple databases (which, I thought were database instances). Guess I was wrong then. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

A DB2 instance is an environment which allows you to store data and run application. You also need to create an instance owner.